# Mediacodec Decoding h264 OutputBuffer Index Returns -1

Tags: android, decode, h.264, android-mediacodec, surface

I am decoding an h264 video stream from a drone on Android using Mediacodec. The drone sends a byte array each time that contains NAL units. The drone document indicates that the IDR-Frame is not included in the returned byte array. So I managed to download the I-Frame file from their website and fed it to the decoder before any other access unit. However, the index returned from mCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer is always -1.

UPDATE 04/01/2016:
Now I correctly feed the decoder with SPS/PPS data and IDR frame before any other NAL units. I observed that the dequeueOutputBuffer returned -3 and then a few positive numbers. After that it returned -1 all the time. So my guess is that there is something wrong with how I handle the access units in the video stream?

```
inputBuffer.put(SPS_PPS,0,SPS_PPS.length);
mCodec.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, SPS_PPS.length, presentationTime, BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG);
```

Some assumptions I've made:

**1. I feed each input buffer of Mediacodec with a complete access unit starting with 00 00 00 01 09**

**2. I decode to a surface from a predefined GLSurface in xml layout, using GLSurface.getHolder().getSurface(). I'm not sure if this is the right way to do.**

My Problems:

**1. outputbuffer index returned is always -1, and no video on the screen**

**2. The byte array returned from the drone always has its latter half to be all 0x00. I don't know if these 0s should all be included in the NAL units as well**

**3. The byte array contains NAL units and I have to split them by myself. But these nal units have only 0x25, 0x27, 0x28, 0x06 and 0x09 types. I only know that 0x09 indicates a AUD**

I really hope anyone could provide even the slightest piece of advice since this thing is driving me crazy these days.

My code snippets:

First of all my main activity class implements the surfaceHolder callback.

Setting up the surface holder:

```
private DjiGLSurfaceView mDjiGLSurfaceView;
mDjiGLSurfaceView = (DjiGLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.DjiSurfaceView_);
mDjiGLSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
```

Read the I-frame from a .264 file to store in byte array -> iframe:

```
BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(is);
buf.read(iframe, 0, iframe.length);
```

My asynchronous processing part:

The DJIReceivedVideoDataCallBack is called when the byte array containing video data is received.

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    Log.e(TAG, "Surface Created!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    format.setString("KEY_MIME", videoFormat);
    try
    {
        mCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(videoFormat);
        mCodec.configure(format, mDjiGLSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface(), null, 0 );
        mCodec.start();

        mReceivedVideoDataCallBack = new DJIReceivedVideoDataCallBack(){
            private int packetLength = 0;
            private ByteBuffer accessUnitBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(50000);
            int inIndex;
            long presentationTime = 0;

            @Override
            public void onResult(byte[] videoBuffer, int size){
                ArrayList<byte []> NAL_Units = splitNALunits(videoBuffer,size);
                //Send the I-Frame first
                if (!seq_start && iframe_ready){
                    inIndex = mCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
                    if (inIndex >= 0) {
                        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = mCodec.getInputBuffer(inIndex);
                        inputBuffer.put(iframe,0,iframe.length);
                        mCodec.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, iframe.length, presentationTime, 0);
                        presentationTime += 100;
                        seq_start = true;
                        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(SHOWTOAST, "I-Frame queued!!!"));
                    }
                }
                for( int i=0; i< NAL_Units.size(); i++ ) {
                    if( NAL_Units.get(i)[4] == 0x09 ) {
                        // Send off the current buffer of data (Access Unit)
                        inIndex = mCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
                        if (inIndex >= 0) {
                            ByteBuffer inputBuffer = mCodec.getInputBuffer(inIndex);
                            if (packetLength > 0)
                                inputBuffer.put(accessUnitBuffer.array(), 0, packetLength);
                            mCodec.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, packetLength, presentationTime, 0);
                            presentationTime += 100;
                            packetLength = 0;
                            accessUnitBuffer.clear();
                            accessUnitBuffer.rewind();
                        }
                    }
                    accessUnitBuffer.put(NAL_Units.get(i));
                    packetLength += NAL_Units.get(i).length;
                }
                MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferinfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                int outputBufferIndex = mCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferinfo, 0);
                handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(SHOWTOAST, "outputBufferIndex = "+ outputBufferIndex));
                while (outputBufferIndex >= 0){
                    mCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, true);
                    outputBufferIndex = mCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferinfo, 0);
                }
            }
        };
        DJIDrone.getDjiCamera().setReceivedVideoDataCallBack(mReceivedVideoDataCallBack);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In media codec.configure() ,if you don't set surface ( set null), it will get the result of decoded and you need draw the image by yourself.

You can search the keyword: "media codec opengl" . you will find the sample.

PS. The format of output is uncertain. (Maybe RGBA)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [MediaExtractor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html%22MediaExtractor%22). If none of supported data sources (see setDataSource method) fits your needs, consider creating custom data source by implementing [MediaDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDataSource.html)

Also, please, note, that some codecs may need you to feed several input buffers before they produce single output buffer.